# ASP.NET User Control Partial Caching by variable values

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching, user-controls

How is it possible to create various cached versions of a user control based on a field within the control. So for example I have a user control that has the following declaration:

```
int someInt = 0;
```

Let's say this variable could be set to any value between 1 and 10. If I want a separate cached user control for each value of the variable - how do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is VaryByControl. See

[Vary by control properties using PartialCaching in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/880937/vary-by-control-properties-using-partialcaching-in-asp-net)

for details.