# ASP.NET UserControl Caching

Tags: asp.net, caching, user-controls

This thing is driving me nuts. I have a UserControl that is called WebUserControl.

I need to cache this control, so I put the following in the WebUserControl.ascx:

```
<%@ OutputCache Duration="240" VaryByParam="FeedName" %>
```

Then I have the Default.aspx file in which I have:

```
      <div class="divInnerLeft" id="L1" runat="server">
            <uc1:WebUserControl FeedId="a1" ID="a1" runat="server" FeedName=""/>
       </div>
       <div class="divInnerMiddle" id="M1" runat="server">
            <uc1:WebUserControl FeedId="a3" ID="a3" runat="server" FeedName=""/>
       </div>
```

In the Page_Load event I set the FeedName property - according to the user preferences.

The problem is that after initially loading the page, the controls are generated OK. But then, in the Page_Load event they are not available again. So the a1 and a3 are null and I cannot set the FeedName for different user.

How to solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: RPM1984: Thaks for the hint. What I wan't to achieve is to have have let's say four UserControls on page. And when the page loads I set some parameter to the user control, and the displayed control is a cached control for the given parameter. 

The VaryByContol also is not helping :(

Comment: Ok - i see what you're trying to do now. Check out this similar SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/880937/vary-by-control-properties-using-partialcaching-in-asp-net.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You realise that **VaryByParam** creates a new entry in the **OutputCache** for each varying parmateter set in the **HTTP GET / POST QueryString**.

Setting the **FeedName** property on the user control reference is not going to vary the cache for the user control.

What exactly are you trying to achieve in regards to caching here?

I think what you're looking for is [VaryByControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z72yz1zs(VS.71).aspx)